# Paypal integration with a DIY shopping cart

Tags: php, paypal

Can some one **PLEASE** give a simple woking example of paypal integration with a DIY shopping cart that bloody well works.

I have implemented my own shopping cart and sinmply want to pass a total cost to paypal and direct the user there for payment.

This package (https://github.com/drewjoh/phpPayPal) seems to fit my requirements:

1)  It involves using a simple php include statement to incorporate it  - no Composer or any other irritating baggage that I also have to figure out.

2) PHP impementation.

3) Simple class and function calls.

Only problem is that it doesn't bloody well work!

I get this from paypal sandbox:

Not Found

The requested URL \cgi-bin\ppapi was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com Port 443

This is my code. How do I make it bloody well work?

Some body really needs to write a comprehensive step by step tutorial on how to use paypal API etc with real working exmples in specific each specific scripting language, and not just useless paypal variable defintiions. The Paypal developer pages are utterley useless - confusing, no concrete examples and scattered all over the place.

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
        session_start();
        require_once "phpPayPal.php";
/*
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre><br><br>";
*/        
        function doPaypalExpressCheckout()
        {
            // Create instance of the phpPayPal class
            $paypal = new phpPayPal(true);

            // Set the amount total for this order.
            $paypal->amount_total = '50.49';
/*        
            $paypal->email = $_SESSION["Email"];
            $paypal->first_name = $_SESSION["GivenName"];
            $paypal->middle_name = $_SESSION["MiddleName"];
            $paypal->last_name = $_SESSION["Surname"];
            $paypal->suffix = "";
            $paypal->address1 = $_SESSION["Address"];
            $paypal->address2 = "";
            $paypal->city = $_SESSION["Suburb"];
            $paypal->state = $_SESSION["State"];
            $paypal->postal_code = $_SESSION["Postcode"];
            $paypal->phone_number = $_SESSION["Phone"]." / ".$_SESSION["Mobile"];

            $paypal->country_code = get_country_code($_SESSION["UserCountry"]);
            $paypal->currency_code = get_currency_code($_SESSION["UserCountry"]);
*/    
            // Make the request
            $paypal->set_express_checkout();

            // If successful, we need to store the token, and then redirect the user to PayPal
            if (!$paypal->_error)
            {
                // Store your token
                $_SESSION['token'] = $paypal->token;

                // Now go to PayPal
                $paypal->set_express_checkout_successful_redirect();
            }
/*
            for ($nI = 0; $nI < count($_SESSION["arrayShoppingCart"]); $nI++)
            {
                //**********************************************************************
                //  array("CategoryIndex"=>$nCategoryIndex,
                //          "ItemIndex"=>$nItemIndex,
                //        "Description"=>$arrayItems[$nItemIndex]["Description"],
                //        "Quantity"=>intval($nQuantity),
                //        "Price"=>floatval($arrayItems[$nItemIndex]["Price"]),
                //        "Volume"=>floatval($arrayItems[$nItemIndex]["Volume"]),
                //        "Postage"=>floatval($arrayItems[$nItemIndex]["Postage"]),
                //        "Options"=>$arrayOptions);
                //***********************************************************************                                                                                                    
                $arrayCartItem = $_SESSION["arrayShoppingCart"][$nI];
                $strCategory = $_SESSION["arrayCategories"][$arrayCartItem["CategoryIndex"]][0];
                $nInventoryIndex = $arrayCartItem["ItemIndex"];
                $arraInventoryItem = $_SESSION["arrayInventory"][$strCategory][$nInventoryIndex];
                $arrayItemCartOptions = $arrayCartItem["Options"];
            }
*/    
        }

        if (isset($_POST["Paypal"]))
        {
            doPaypalExpressCheckout();
        }

?>
```

Comment: You sound **bloody well** angry... I'm not sure we need to know that

Comment: I would recommend checking out my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) instead.  It's very straight forward and has fully functional samples as well as empty templates for all the API calls.  The best part is it all works out of the box.  :)  This could all be done in a matter of minutes.  It does work with Composer, but you don't have to install it that way.  You can simply download and extract/upload like anything else if you want to (though, I'd really recommend you learn Composer.  It's a huge time saver.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) PayPal Standard implementation ([controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/payment/pp_standard.php) and [view](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/payment/pp_standard.tpl)).

It is very well done and simple to understand.

In controller `ControllerPaymentPPStandard`, method `index` it will create the paypal products form and redirect (submit form) to paypal. Then paypal will make a callback request on `notify_url`, method `callback` and depending on payment status you do various things.

I hope this helps.